# How can I lock and unlock specific levels in an iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, game-development

I'm working on my first game and would like to lock my levels, and have them unlock when a certain score is reached on the previous level.  I'm not sure how or where I would implement this.  Here is the code from the start screen.  Thanks for your help and please let me know if more info is needed!

```
@implementation StartScreen{
    SKSpriteNode *level2;
    SKSpriteNode *level3;
    SKSpriteNode *level4;
    SKSpriteNode *level5;
    SKSpriteNode *level6;
    SKSpriteNode *level7;
    SKSpriteNode *level8;
    SKSpriteNode *level9;

    SKAction *clicSound;

}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
        [background setSize:self.size];
        [background setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)];

        [self addChild:background];

        SKSpriteNode *logo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"logo"];
        [logo setSize:CGSizeMake(logo.size.width, logo.size.height)];
        [logo setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2 + 150)];

        [self addChild:logo];

        SKSpriteNode *highscorebutton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"highscorebutton"];
        highscorebutton.name = @"highscorebutton";
        [highscorebutton setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2 - 100)];
        [self addChild:highscorebutton];

        level2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"level2"];
        level2.name = @"level2";
        [level2 setPosition:CGPointMake(50, self.size.height/2 +10 + 25)];
        [self addChild:level2];

        level3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"level3"];
        level3.name = @"level3";
        [level3 setPosition:CGPointMake(120, self.size.height/2 +10 +25)];
        [self addChild:level3];

        level4 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"level4"];
        level4.name = @"level4";
        [level4 setPosition:CGPointMake(190, self.size.height/2 +10 +25)];
        [self addChild:level4];

        level5 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"level5"];
        level5.name = @"level5";
        [level5 setPosition:CGPointMake(260, self.size.height/2 +10 +25)];
        [self addChild:level5];

        level6 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"level6"];
        level6.name = @"level6";
        [level6 setPosition:CGPointMake(50, self.size.height/2 -10 -25)];
        [self addChild:level6];

        level7 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"level7"];
        level7.name = @"level7";
        [level7 setPosition:CGPointMake(120, self.size.height/2 -10 -25)];
        [self addChild:level7];

        level8 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"level8"];
        level8.name = @"level8";
        [level8 setPosition:CGPointMake(190, self.size.height/2 -10 -25)];
        [self addChild:level8];

        level9 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"level9"];
        level9.name = @"level9";
        [level9 setPosition:CGPointMake(260, self.size.height/2 -10 -25)];
        [self addChild:level9];

        [[GameCenterManager sharedManager] setDelegate:self];


    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if([node.name isEqualToString:@"highscorebutton"]){
        clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
        [self runAction:clicSound];
        BOOL isAvailable = [[GameCenterManager sharedManager] checkGameCenterAvailability];

        if(isAvailable){

            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;

            [[GameCenterManager sharedManager] presentLeaderboardsOnViewController:vc];

        }else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"High Score" message: @"Game Center is currently unavailable. Make sure you are logged in." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show];

        }
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"level2"]){
        clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
        [self runAction:clicSound];
        SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:.8];
        [level2 runAction:action completion:^(void){
            [self selectLevel:2];
            SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.6f];
            GameScreen *game = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
            [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
        }];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"level3"]){
                clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
                [self runAction:clicSound];
            SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:.8];
            [level3 runAction:action completion:^(void){
                [self selectLevel:3];
                SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.6f];
                GameScreen *game = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
                [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
            }];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"level4"]) {
            clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
            [self runAction:clicSound];
            SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:.8];
            [level4 runAction:action completion:^(void){
                [self selectLevel:4];
                SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.6f];
                GameScreen *game = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
                [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
            }];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"level5"]) {
            clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
            [self runAction:clicSound];
            SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:.8];
            [level5 runAction:action completion:^(void){
               [self selectLevel:5];
                SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.6f];
                GameScreen *game = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
                [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
            }];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"level6"]) {
            clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
            [self runAction:clicSound];
            SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:.8];
            [level6 runAction:action completion:^(void){
                [self selectLevel:6];
                SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.6f];
                GameScreen *game = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
                [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
            }];

    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"level7"]) {
            clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
            [self runAction:clicSound];
            SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:.8];
            [level7 runAction:action completion:^(void){
                [self selectLevel:7];
                SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.6f];
                GameScreen *game = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
                [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
            }];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"level8"]) {
            clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
            [self runAction:clicSound];
            SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:.8];
            [level8 runAction:action completion:^(void){
                [self selectLevel:8];
                SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.6f];
                GameScreen *game = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
                [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
            }];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"level9"]) {
            clicSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
            [self runAction:clicSound];
            SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:.8];
            [level9 runAction:action completion:^(void){
                [self selectLevel:9];
                SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:.6f];
                GameScreen *game = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
                [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
            }];
    }

}
-(void)selectLevel:(int)level{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setInteger:level forKey:@"level"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
- (void)gameCenterManager:(GameCenterManager *)manager authenticateUser:(UIViewController *)gameCenterLoginController
{

    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc presentViewController:gameCenterLoginController animated:YES completion:^{


    }];
}
```

Comment: What levels are there in Xcode that you want to lock/unlock and what kind of game has the individual players using Xcode? Or do you mean something else when you say Xcode.

Comment: I want to initially lock levels 3 through 9 on the start screen of the game, unlock level 3 when the player reaches a certain score on level 2, then progressively unlock the rest the same way.

Comment: You are missing the point, learn the names of the tools you use. Xcode is an editor/compiler/debugger, it has nothing to do with the running app. The language is Objective-C and the APIs are CocoaTouch. What is running is the iOS app.

Comment: I think this question is more amount saving information in the app, and how one would go about locking/unlocking features of an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use NSUserDefaults to handle this type of conditions. Use this code to save your score for level 1.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:scoreCount forKey:@"ScoreLevel1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and for allowance in level 2, use this code

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ScoreLevel1"] >= level1Maximum)
{
      //allow to enter in level 2.
      // put your code here to present level 2 in this condition.
}
```

you can do this for all your levels for locking and unlocking condition with different keywords and limits and refresh your level checking after some limit of score reached.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NSUserDefaults` and when the game opens check to see if you have beaten the levels you would require. Once you beat the required levels / reach the required score, save that into `NSUserDefaults` and then your app will remember what is locked and unlocked.

Comment: Oh, well then don't worry about it!